# system.drawing.image to spfile

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a image that I need to save in a Sharepoint site under shared documents

For various reasons the image has to be in a system.drawing.image and be saved in the shared documents within the sharepoint site. it does not have to be saved in a local hard disk.

Have you got any solution?

so far I am gtrying

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 byte[] imagebyte = ms.ToArray();
```

then Savebinary function of the streamreader  but no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starter for ten, you will need to change some of the hard coded settings in here

```
 public void addToSharepointImageList(string folderName, string fileName, byte[] content)
    {
        string path = @"\\yoursite\yourlistname\";
        string baseSharePointPath = "http://yoursite/";
        string listName = "yourlistname"; 
        SharePointImagingService.Imaging svc = null;

        try
        {
            path += folderName;
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            #region create sharepoint service

            svc = new SharePointImagingService.Imaging();

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            svc.Credentials = nc;
            //svc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            svc.Url = baseSharePointPath + listName+ "/_vti_bin/imaging.asmx";
            svc.Discover();

            #endregion

            svc.Upload(baseSharePointPath + listName, folderName, content, fileName, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //deal with error
        }
        finally
        {
            svc.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

or, if you are trying to just save the file directly to a non-image list you can treat sharepoint as a giant file share and just open a filestream and write the byte array there.

Comment: Yes I was looking more for the last option almost done I need to name the file

Comment: Since sharepoint uses webdav you can simply write the file to \\sharepointserver\shared documents.

Comment: @brianbrinley, Really? works fine for me with Foundation 2010...  admittedly you cannot set any of the additional properties using the direct write method, they all get set to defaults, but the file goes in and is accessable just fine. same as if you open the list in Explorer and drag-drop.

Comment: yup thats exactly what it mimics, but i didn't see the requirement to set any additional fields.

Answer (score 3):

After a while I managed to find a solution avoiding picture libraries

```
   void imageSave(System.Drawing.Image imageTobeSaved)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sptestsite/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders["Shared%20Documents"];


                var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                string filename = "picture.jpg";          
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                imageTobeSaved.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.jpg);
                byte[] ImageByte = ms.ToArray();

                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(filename, ImageByte);
                myLibrary.Update();


            }
        }
    }
```